# how to generate barcodes using java

Tags: java, barcode

Is it possible to generate barcodes using java? If so how can i do that? Appreciate any information.

Comment: Google can show you some libraries that would work with Java.

Answer (score 5):

There are some existing components out there that'll help. For instance:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/barbecue/
- http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) generates QR codes, EAN-8, EAN-13, UPC-A, Code 128, and Code 39.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this how to, using ZXing. http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/09/java-barcode-api/

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```